# Swift 4 json Decoding with an array inside

Tags: json, swift

I have the following Json data from a web page

```
[{"time": "2019-02-04", "lat": 0.0, "lng": 0.0, "base_stations": ["ABCD"], "best_server": "6652", "avg_rssi": -84.67605633802818, "reception_count": 213.0, "link_quality": "GOOD"}, {"time": "2019-02-07", "lat": 90.71, "lng": 100.64, "base_stations": ["CDEF", "XPTO", "ZZEEG"], "best_server": "YYYY", "avg_rssi": -133.0, "reception_count": 3.0, "link_quality": "EXCELLENT"},{....},{....}]
```

And I would like to decode it. I was thinking something like this:

```
let DamasDriveAddress_Grid = "http://bbbba.fff.com/json_pg"
let url_Grid = URL(string: DamasDriveAddress_Grid)!
let jsonData_Grid = try! Data(contentsOf: url_Grid)

struct Test_Grid: Codable {
    let time: Date
    let lat: Double
    let lng: Double
    let base_stations: [Array]
    let best_server:String
    let avg_rssi:Double
    let reception_count: Double
    let link_quality: String

}

let jsonDecoder_Grid = JSONDecoder()
let Grid = try? jsonDecoder_Grid.decode(Array<Test_Grid>.self,
                                          from: jsonData_Grid)
```

But it does not work.

Can someone please help me.

Thank you

Comment: what error do you get ? There are a lot of json decode questions in stackoverflow.. Have you tried all of them ?

Comment: Don't `try?`. Never `try?` when decoding JSON. **catch** the error,  it's very descriptive. `time` is `String` and `base_stations` is `[String]` not `[Array]`. And please conform to the Swift naming convention that variable names are *lowerCamelCased*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base_stations` should be a `[String]`

```
struct Test_Grid: Codable {
    let time: Date
    let lat: Double
    let lng: Double
    let base_stations: [String] <-- here
    let best_server:String
    let avg_rssi:Double
    let reception_count: Double
    let link_quality: String

}
```

Also, you should specify a date decoding strategy:

```
let jsonDecoder_Grid = JSONDecoder()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
jsonDecoder_Grid.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it with a String in base_stations but when I decode it it comes empty [...]. The Base Stations do have several items inside : "base_stations": ["61F0", "9692", "9726"]

Comment: @Vasco `base_stations` should be a `[String]`, not `String`. I can't reproduce your described behaviour.